# Android:Recently Added songs list using media store

Tags: android

I am working on simple audio media player. I am using media store to get information of all songs stored on the sdcard. So far So good. Everything is working fine.

But I am stuck now. How can I get last added (recently added) songs using media store?

Regards,
Niral

Answer (score 5):

This is from the source of the Default Music Player in Android 2.3

```
    private void playRecentlyAdded() {
    // do a query for all songs added in the last X weeks
    int X = MusicUtils.getIntPref(this, "numweeks", 2) * (3600 * 24 * 7);
    final String[] ccols = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
    String where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - X);
    Cursor cursor = MusicUtils.query(this, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            ccols, where, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    if (cursor == null) {
        // Todo: show a message
        return;
    }
    try {
        int len = cursor.getCount();
        long [] list = new long[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            list[i] = cursor.getLong(0);
        }
        MusicUtils.playAll(this, list, 0);
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but when I looked up at the default android music player source, i found out that there is a "recently added" playlist in media store. Its id in **MediaStore.Audio.Playlists** is **-1**.

**EDIT:**

After further research, I found out that -1 is just a value to indicate that it does not exist on the Playlist table.
You may use the following solution instead:

Upon querying **MediaStore.Audio.Media**, add this to your where clause condition:

`MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + ">" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - NUM_OF_DAYS);`

NUM_OF_DAYS refers to how old your audio file is stored in your SD card.

Take Note: query from  **MediaStore.Audio.Media**, not **MediaStore.Audio.Playlist**.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom list that you maintain add one more integer field 'dateAdded' and to access that use

```
    int dateAddedIndex = internalContentCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED);
    if (dateAddedIndex != -1) {
        songs.setDateAdded(externalContentCursor.getInt(externalContentCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED)));
    }
```

After getting this sort the list according to the time they were added

```
public static List<Songs> getTopRecentAdded(List<Songs> list) {
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Songs>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Songs left, Songs right) {
                    return left.getDateAdded() - right.getDateAdded();
                }
            });

            Collections.reverse(list);
            return list;
        }
```

This will return the list which contain song at first which was added last.